# unexpected token : ( in HQL

Tags: java, hql

I am getting error as **unexpected token :(** 
below the query, but this same query is working fine in **SQL**

```
"SELECT slh.assetId,slh.mapHierarchy "
+ "FROM AssetHistory slh "
+ "INNER JOIN "
+ "(SELECT assetId, MAX(lastUpdated) AS MaxDateTime "
+ "FROM AssetHistory "
+ "GROUP BY assetId) slh2 "
+ "ON slh.assetId = slh2.assetId "
+ "AND slh.lastUpdated =slh2.MaxDateTime ";
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Here is the error log:

> Jan 25, 2016 4:04:32 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter
>   reportError ERROR: line 1:89: unexpected token: ( Jan 25, 2016 4:04:32
>   PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError ERROR: line
>   1:89: unexpected token: (
>   **line 1:89: unexpected token: (**    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromJoin(HqlBaseParser.java:1661)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1380)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:731)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:323)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:186)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)

and

> ERROR: line 1:106: unexpected token: max line 1:106:**unexpected
>   token: max**  at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromRange(HqlBaseParser.java:1544)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.fromClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1388)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:731)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:323)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:186)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should move subquery from join to where clause.

```
"SELECT slh.assetId,slh.mapHierarchy "
+ "FROM AssetHistory slh "
+" WHERE (slh.assetId, slh.lastUpdated)"
+ " IN 
+ "(SELECT assetId, MAX(lastUpdated) AS MaxDateTime "
+ "FROM AssetHistory "
+ "GROUP BY assetId);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think HQL does not support subqueries in `FROM` clause.

[14.13. Subqueries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries)

Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.

Comment: yes you are right, hql is not supporting sub queries in FROM clause,
the sub queries should be WHERE or SELECT clause